# Prove that ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to the zero function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Fix $a,b∈R$ with $a<b$. Define the sequence ${f_n}$ of functions by $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x)=x/n$. Prove that ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to the zero function.

I somewhat understand how to do this, but if you could explain it, that would be appreciated.

Comment: It's important for you to tell us what you do NOT understand, or it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: In this simple case you can actually calculate $\| f_n - 0 \|_\infty = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)|$ explicitly, and then deal with the convergence of a sequence of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that, given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $|f_n(x)-0|<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in [a,b]$.

I'll give you a hint regarding how to do this. Since $a,b$ are fixed, $|f_n(x)-0|=|x/n| \le {1 \over n}\max\left \{ |a|,|b| \right \}$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.